# Generating a circuit that match a given boolean function using bi-decomposition

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I am looking for an step by step explanation of how to get the circuit of an given boolean function using **bi-recomposition**.

I have a given function like:

> f(a,b,c,d)=abc~d+ab~cd+a~bcd+~abcd

The normal ways I know are:

A.) Karnaugh plan:

[image: Truth Table]

k-map:

[image: k-map]

result:

1. **DNF: f=~abcd + a~bcd + ab~cd + abc~d**
2. **KNF: (~a+~b+~c+~d) * (a+b) * (a+c) * (b+c) * (a+d) * (b+d) * (c+d)**

DNS in Gates(a~bcd): 
[image: DNS for f(abcd)]

B.) Second method: minimisation by Quine & McCluskey:

The rsult is also: **f=(~abcd)+(a~bcd)+(a*b*~c*d)+(a*b*c*~d)**

([tool](http://byteflex.net/boolsolve/)) with input 1: a,b,c,d and 2: [7,11,13,14]

[image: circuit]

**13 logic gates**

---

C.) Simplifying the function on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%20%C2%A0%28~a%20AND%20b%20AND%20c%20AND%20d%20OR%20a%20AND%20~b%20AND%20c%20AND%20d%20%20OR%20a%20AND%20b%20AND%20~c%20AND%20d%20OR%20a%20AND%20b%20AND%20c%20AND%20~d%29)

The result is: **f=(abc)XOR(abd)XOR(acd)XOR(bcd)**
[image: result circuit wolframalpha]

**11 logic gates**

(tool used for visualisation: [logic.ly](http://logic.ly/demo/))

---

D.) With bi-decomposition I found this result:

[image]

**7 logic gates** (performance has to be tested by benchmarks)

But how to get there? A step by step explanation / pseudo code is what I am looking for.

Comment: Just so you know, XOR gates are much less efficient in implementation than most other gates, and AND/OR gates are less efficient than NAND/NOR gates.  Simple comparisons of number of gates is not the best metric to use.

Comment: @Justin thank you for the hint! I will edit the "best result" but the question in the end is still the same.

Comment: Hint : do an image search or _k-map xor_. You'll notices a checkerboard pattern.  XOR gates are less efficient then other gates, but more efficient then  the sum of the parts to match the same functionality. So use XOR gates on when necessary.

Comment: I can't help with bi-decomposition, but your netlist does an arithmetic \$a+b+c+d==3\$ so you can make it with two adders with carry. The resulting equation is \$((a  \:xor \: b) + (c\:  xor  \:d))(a\:b + c\:d)\$, similar to the one in figure 3. You car read the equation as *one of the sums should have carry, and one of the sums should be odd*

Comment: what exactly is the question?  is it how todo this in code rather than visual tricks that kmap's facilitate?

Comment: @JonRB The question is abount the steps you need to perform to get from a given function (example) to the simplified form using bi-decomposition. To get the circuit from the formula I can manage. (so no visual "tricks") pseudocode would be nice in a detailed answer.

Comment: Did you ask this because you couldn't afford the [full] paper where you found those results? https://books.google.com/books?id=M_ZEBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA822 Also, this is not simply bi-decomposition.

Comment: By the way, the paper has a free preprint. http://www.informatik.tu-freiberg.de/prof2/publikationen/ICSEng_2014_SFD.pdf So -1 for combination of laziness and not disclosing the source.

Comment: Since I suspect you may have been stumped by the talk of derivatives (of Boolean functions) in that paper, and
since you also don't seem to recognize the gulf between two-level optimization and multi-level techniques, I warmly recommend you [these free lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZ9qNFMHZ-A4PBU9gjF8Kpy2tbRrxqWmR).

Comment: Cofactors and respectively derivatives are in lectures 2 and 3; multi-level optimization starts in lecture 18. I don't think he covers bi-decomposition (which isn't all that used in industry, as far as I know), but you'll learn the more standard techniques for multi-level optimization, which will give you fewer gates than k-maps.

Comment: The other topics that you'd need to understand well to grok that paper unfortunately are out of the realm of the staple graduate courses. I don't think you'll find [SNF](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~alanmi/publications/2001/rm01_exa.pdf) in any textbooks or courses yet.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Thank you, I will study this material. And y I did not get the steps to the solution. That is why I asked for a detailed answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overal trick to the bi-decomposition solution is with identfying XORs.

A 4 variable XOR of \$X \oplus Y \oplus X \oplus W\$ generates the below Karnaugh map (k-map). Notice the checkerboard pattern.
[image]

Except the final row and column, it lines up with your k-map. Therefor we can use the 4 variable XOR as a base and mask the the undesired ones. With your table, you want to mask ones when \$\bar{A}\bar{D}\$ or \$\bar{B}\bar{C}\$. The inverse (when you allow ones) is then the equation \$\overline{\bar{A}\bar{D}+\bar{B}\bar{C}}\$ which is simplified to \$(A+D)(B+C)\$, proof below.

$$
\overline{\bar{A}\bar{D}+\bar{B}\bar{C}} \\
\equiv (\overline{\bar{A}\bar{D}})(\overline{\bar{B}\bar{C}}) \\
\equiv (\overline{(\bar{A})}+\overline{(\bar{D})})(\overline{(\bar{B})}+\overline{(\bar{C})}) \\
\equiv (A+D)(B+C)
$$
Add in the XOR and get \$(A \oplus B \oplus C \oplus D)(A+D)(B+C)\$. This is 4 gates; one 4-input XOR, two 2-input OR, and one 3-input AND. If everything is turned to 2-input gates, then it becomes 7 gates; three XOR, two OR, and two AND. This matches the bi-decomposition Fig.2.

[image: bi-decomposition Fig.2 proof]

$$
(A \oplus B \oplus C \oplus D)(A+D)(B+C) \\
\equiv ((A \oplus B) \oplus (C \oplus D))(A+D)(B+C)\\
\equiv (((A \oplus B) \oplus (C \oplus D))(A+D)) (B+C) \, \, \# \, as \, 2-input \, gates
$$

The bi-decomposition Fig.3 uses an approach that grabs the smallest XOR; \$A \oplus B\$ and \$C \oplus D\$, then gate out the Rest. \$(A \oplus B)CD\$ and \$AB(C \oplus D)\$. Finally ORing them together \$(A \oplus B)CD + AB(C \oplus D)\$. Then convert to 2-input gates \$((A \oplus B)C)D + A(B(C \oplus D))\$. This now matches Fig.3.

$$
grp0 = (A \oplus B)CD \, \, \# \, first \, smallest \, XOR \, group \\
grp1 = AB(C \oplus D) \, \, \# \, second \, smallest \, XOR \, group \\
grp0 + grp1 = (A \oplus B)CD + AB(C \oplus D) \\
\equiv ((A \oplus B)C)D + A(B(C \oplus D)) \, \, \# \, as \, 2-input \, gates
$$

[image: bi-decomposition Fig.3 proof]

---

I had to lookup the definition of "bi-decomposition", and my explication is too big to fit in a comment. "Bi-decomposition" used to be called "grouping"; which I vaguely remember my professor calling it many years ago. The process is to taking a function and composing it as sub-functions. This approach is piratically useful where the only neighboring 1s on a K-map are diagonal. XOR/XNOR then express the sub-functions.

The best online description I found are:

- [Logic Functions and Equations: Binary Models for Computer Science](https://books.google.com/books?id=7FMFCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA303&lpg=PA303&dq=On+bi-decomposition+of+logicfunctions&source=bl&ots=Wio5QU-noN&sig=GXKyT3nboT0LbqV6EhPF1DVNHLA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBGoVChMI9Y2jneaNyQIVDN9jCh1EfgnR) by Christian Posthoff, Bernd Steinbach
- [An Algorithm for Bi-Decomposition of Logic
  Functions](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~alanmi/publications/2001/dac01.pdf) by Alan Mishchenko, Bernd Steinbach, Marek Perkowski

Comment: Thank you a lot for your solution! Just as far as I understood the bi-decomposition takes the boolean function and tries to divide it into sub functions, minimize them and than put it together again. So how to find and generate "good" subfunctions. To solve functions in general with bi-decomposition. Am I right?

Comment: @kimliv, the full explication was too bit for a comment, so I added it in my answer. In summary, yes, you got the idea; sub-functions

Comment: Actually, the final graphs from the OP's question are take from [a more recent paper by Steinbach](http://www.informatik.tu-freiberg.de/prof2/publikationen/ICSEng_2014_SFD.pdf) (without disclosure where they came from). Furthermore that paper contains the full algorithm by which the results were obtained.